# How to use menu and ListView simultaneously in a Navigation View

Tags: android, listview, menu, navigationview

I have created a navigation view inside which a dynamic list is created at run time from the data retrieved from server. It works fine, and shows the list once a successful communication has been done with the server. The problem is that I am unable to add items like Settings and About Us to the bottom of the list. The following layout (activity_main.xml) results in menu items overshadowing the list view items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:elevation="@dimen/padding"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_items"

        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat
            android:id="@+id/categories_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_side"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_side"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_header_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
            />


    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And this is the contents of navigation_items.xml (menu resource):

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:id="@+id/nav_bottom"
    android:orderInCategory="0">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/settings"
        android:title="@string/settings" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/about_us"
        android:icon="@drawable/info"
        android:title="@string/about_us" />


</group>
</menu>
```

The result on emulator is as follows:
[image]

Comment: can you not add menu items in the list instead of `app:menu="@menu/navigation_items"`. Like listview with default items initially and when you have new items show them using listview

Comment: Can you please post your Java code.

Comment: @Raghunandan no, I have to create the list on the fly.

Comment: @JasonStack `app:menu="@menu/navigation_items"` contains settings item?

Comment: I'm not sure where users got the idea to put arbitrary things inside a `NavigationView`. It's not really meant to be used like that. If you want your `ListView` and `NavigationView` stacked, then pull the `ListView` out, and put them both inside a vertical `LinearLayout`, for example.

Comment: Yes @Raghunandan

Comment: @JasonStack you can add a footer to listview with settings and about us?

Comment: @MikeM. I need the list for filtering the items in my main list view. Where else do you recommend I perform category filtering?

Comment: @Raghunandan I am not sure if appending "settings" to my list view is a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine, I'm just saying that sticking other `View`s directly inside a `NavigationView` is pretty much always going to turn out wonky. You can still have both of those things in your drawer, just put them inside another `ViewGroup` that acts as the drawer. A drawer can be any kind of `View` or `ViewGroup`. It doesn't have to be a `NavigationView`. That's just what the new templates put there by default. You just need to make sure the drawer `View` has the `layout_gravity` attribute.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM. Is there a better solution to filtering items instead of using the navigation drawer?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your overall design is, so I can't really say, but I don't see anything wrong with having both of those things in your drawer.

Comment: @JasonStack are you looking for https://i.imgur.com/3vKov0v.jpg ? the one at the bottom can be your settings section?

Comment: @Raghunandan, yes, except your items are all static (read from menu resource), while I will have both static and dynamic elements.

Comment: @JasonStack  no i created a items using recyclerview with header and other view types and used a ScrimInsetsRelativeLayout and put the settings in bottom and recyclelview above it. But this requires a lot of code while there are others ways to achieve the same as already mentioned you can move recyclerview outside the navigationview. wra both of them in RelativeLayout . You can add some shadows as well to the bottom section

Comment: @Raghunandan can you show your xml code? Did you use a ViewGroup?

Comment: Hey @MikeM. I have two questions. ViewGroup does not have setNavigationItemSelectedListener, then how can it be used instead of NavigationView? Also, how do I embed a menu inside a ViewGroup?

Comment: You'd still set the `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` on the `NavigationView` like normal. Nothing changes with its code functionalities. You're just wrapping it in another `ViewGroup` so it lays out differently. I'm not sure what you mean by "embed a menu inside a ViewGroup".

Comment: @JasonStack i am posting it now

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to achieve what you want is

```
<com.example.raghu.drawersample.ScrimInsetsRelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:layout_above="@+id/nav_view"
        android:id="@+id/item_list"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</com.example.raghu.drawersample.ScrimInsetsRelativeLayout>
```

> ViewGroup does not have setNavigationItemSelectedListener, then how
>   can it be used instead of NavigationView? Also, how do I embed a menu
>   inside a ViewGroup?

You are just wrapping your `NavigationView` and `ListView/RecyclerView` in  a `RelativeLayout`

Its upto you whether you use RecyclerView or ListView. You can use  `navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)` normally.

Picked ScrimInsetsRelativeLayout code from https://github.com/mikepenz/Materialize/blob/develop/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialize/view/ScrimInsetsRelativeLayout.java

I used that cause i added a header to recylerview and i wanted the status bar to look exactly like in the pic below.

You end up with

[image]

> I am not sure if appending "settings" to my list view is a good idea

The other way is to add your settings items as a footer to your recyclerview. You can see this pattern in gmail. I am not sure why its not a good idea. If you have more items user still needs to scroll down.

While fixing the footer(settings & help) at the bottom with shadow at the top is what you see in inbox app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Adding ScrimInsetsRelativeLayout.java to my code results in several unresolved dependencies. How can I solve that? And another question, why cannot use a simple RelativeLayout?

Comment: @JasonStack you can use relativeLayout. i wanted the header to cover the status bar also . so i used RelativeLayout. For your case i guess its ok to use just RelativeLayout

Comment: I had errors in the code for ScrimeInsetsRelativeLayout. I couldn't make it work. I might consider doing filtering in another activity and not in the drawer.

Comment: @JasonStack why not use a RelativeLayout. Also the error is because you not copied the attrs.xml from the liked repository